# Garbage collection libraries

Tags: c, garbage-collection

Are there any "good" C libraries for garbage collection?

I know about the Boehm GC, is it maintained nowadays?

What about http://tinygc.sourceforge.net?

What are your experiences with these libraries?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Boehm's Garbage Collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). Many projects I have worked with use it.

Comment: The drawback is: it is not plattform independent, as most GCs for C.

Comment: @Peter Miehle: Yes it is: "The distribution includes ports to most standard PC and UNIX/Linux platforms. The collector should work on Linux, *BSD, recent Windows versions, MacOS X, HP/UX, Solaris, Tru64, Irix and a few other operating systems."

Comment: @amphetamachine "The collector is not completely portable, but the distribution includes ports to most standard PC and UNIX/Linux platforms."

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know of a good, easy, and effective GC for C, I would like to weigh in some thoughts.

For many years, I avoided heap allocations for fear of memory leaks. And I do not know of any way to have a memory leak without allocating from the heap.

But I do not know of any better way to return memory from a function (such as a string, or an array of structs) than by heap allocation. Heap allocation allows you to allocate precisely the amount of memory you need without knowing how much memory you need at compile time. If your program will load files to memory, you probably will not know at compile time how much memory you might need. If you go the static memory route, then you always have to allocate the maximum memory you might ever need. Then your program can become a memory hog when it does not need to be. Heap is better.

But then keeping track of heap allocations can be difficult in some kinds of programs, for example, a program that has many modules inserting and deleting elements from an in-memory database. And memory leaks can be so difficult to solve. A good GC seems to me a very good way to stop memory leaks because of the automated tracking and freeing of heap allocations.

So, this post responds to the comment that "If you have problems in C using malloc() and free() correctly, you should switch to another language." If the programming problem  is complicated and the solution needs heap allocations, the even the best programmers will have to debug memory leaks.

In some programs, there could be an alternative to using garbage collection: You can assume that an operating system will free all the program's allocations when the program terminates. So, your main program might be able to call a second program that uses heap allocations then writes results to a file and terminates. I tested this on Windows. I observed that Windows deallocated heap memory that my test program allocated on the test program's termination. I ran the test program many times. There was no diminishing of available memory.

Of course, having a second program that runs a short while and terminates is often not a viable solution.